# Grating offline_access to public apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, single-page-application

What's your opinion regarding grating offline_access to public applications?
I've looked through the standard and have not found an explicit indication that grating public apps the offline_access is a big security issue.

I think it is as a public app are not capable of securely keeping their password, let alone a refresh token. At the same time I see a lot of samples with browser apps that use the refresh_token flow, so it may be a common strategy to prevent having the user redirected to the identity provider.

My goal is to find a proper way to get another access_token using AJAX so that the user does not have the page refreshed or be redirected to the identity provider.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), the issuance of a refresh token is [not permitted with the implicit grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) and it at the discretion of the authorization server for the other gran types.

The [OpenID Connect specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess) is a bit more restrictive by mentionning that the authorization server `MUST ignore the offline_access request unless the Client is using a response_type value that would result in an Authorization Code being returned`.

Anyway, those specifications permit the issuance of a refresh token for a public client if the [`refresh tokens can receive an acceptable level of protection`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1).

[Possible threats](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.2) are identified and countermeasures could be (non-exhaustive list):

- Secure refresh tokens storage (encrypted folder/disk).
- Lock(s) to prevent unauthorized device/application access
- Possibility to revoke the access tokens/refresh tokens
- Rotation of the resfresh tokens
- Combine refresh token request with device identification

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!